# Status bar overlap notification badge in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11

This is UIViewcontroller class . I added a badge on 
On Navigation bar . Its working fine on iOS 10 . But 
In iOS 11 , notification badge is overlapped by status bar
. How can I rid off this problem .

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at it using the “Debug View Hierarchy”-button and inspecting the `clipsToBounds` value of all superviews?

Comment: Yes i cheched it .

Comment: the custom view height in rightBarButtonItem should not be more than navigation bar height. Please check your custom view height, update subviews frame fit inside custom view.

Comment: Sorry For late reply ... Did you concentrate it is working fine on lower versions than iOS 11 . Its working fine on iOS 10 @Mats.

Comment: Sorry For late reply ... Did you concentrate it is working fine on lower versions than iOS 11 . If custom view height is an issues then what problems with iOS 10 .Its working fine on iOS 10  @AshokPolu

Comment: disable safe area layout feature from Xcode